# Best way to manage big files downloads

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, server

I'm looking for the best way to manage the download of my products on the web.
Each of them weighs between 2 and 20 Go.
Each of them is approximatively downloaded between 1 and 1000 times a day by our customers.

I've tried to use Amazon S3 but the download speed isn't good and it quickly becomes expensive.
I've tried to use Amazon S3 + CloudFront but files are too large and the downloads too rare: the files didn't stay in the cache.
Also, I can't create torrent files in S3 because the files size is too large.
I guess the cloud solutions (such as S3, Azure, Google Drive...) work well only for small files, such as image / css / etc.

Now, I'm using my own servers. It works quite well but it is really more complex to manage...

Is there a better way, a perfect way to manage this sort of downloads?

Comment: May I ask how to provide users access to download them? Do they download it through a web application? if yes, which technology are you using for your application? and if no, Are they downloading the files through FTP or what?

Comment: Which region is your bucket in? Where are your customers located that say it's a slow download? What is your definition of a slow download? How fast is the connection the download is happening over?

Comment: I'm not sure your blanket statement that "cloud solutions work well only for small files" is very accurate. Especially since you only seem to have tested one solution. I've found Google Drive and Dropbox for Business to both perform well when sharing very large files.

Comment: @behroozdalvandi: we only provide http links for our users atm, but we advise them to use a download manager soft.

Comment: @MattHouser: we have 7 buckets, one for every region, as our users are located worldwide. But even with that, people used to complain to our support team, especially when a product is downloaded a lot at the same time. And it is expensive, at least $2000/month.

Comment: @mbaird: You're right, and that's a part of my question. I've heard that Google Drive has restrictive bandwidth daily limits... I did not try Dropbox yet, but now I'm afraid and it takes a long time to switch all the files!

Comment: Why are your files so large (2-20 GB)?

Comment: @jarmod I don't manage the files myself, they are commercial products (virtual instruments with many samples).

Comment: When you say it is expensive, are you referring to Data Transfer prices? They range from 9-14c/GB in most locations (Brazil is costlier). For $2000 you'd get approx 20TB of data transfer, which is 1000-10,000 downloads of your files. Is that accurate? Are your own servers significantly cheaper, taking into account compute + data?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, you're right. We manage approximatively 50 files, each of this file is downloaded between 1 and 1000 times a day. Our downloads seems better with 3 dedicated servers that cost $150 each at online.net (we have less user complaints). But, as I said, it is more complex to manage. Our main deception is that for the price, S3 don't scale well: users always have some problems downloading files when we have special offers on our website.

Comment: @mbaird Bad news from Dropbox for Business: "The total amount of traffic that all of your links and file requests together can generate without getting banned is about 200 GB per day."

Answer (score 4):

This is a huge problem and we see it when dealing with folks in the movie or media business: they generate HUGE video files that need to be shared on a tight schedule.  Some of them resort to physically shipping hard drives.

When "ordered and guaranteed data delivery" is required (e.g. HTTP, FTP, rsync, nfs, etc.) the network transport is usually performed with TCP.  But TCP implementations are quite sensitive to packet loss, round-trip time (RTT), and the size of the pipe, between the sender and receiver.  Some TCP implementations also have a hard time filling big pipes (limits on the max bandwidth-delay product; BDP = bit rate * propagation delay).

The ideal solution would need to address all of these concerns.

Reducing the RTT usually means reducing the distance between sender and receiver.  Rule of thumb, reducing your RTT by half can double your max throughput (or cut your turnaround time in half).  Just for context, I'm seeing an RTT from US East Coast to US West Coast as ~80-85ms.

Big deployments typically use a content delivery network (CDN) like Akamai or AWS CloudFront, to reduce the RTT (e.g. ~5-15ms).  Simply stated, the CDN service provider makes arrangements with local/regional telcos to deploy content-caching servers on-premise in many cities, and sells you the right to use them.

But control over a cached resource's time-to-live (TTL) can depend on your service level agreement ($).  And cache memory is not infinite, so idle resources might be purged to make room for newly requested data, especially if the cache is shared with others.

In your case, it sounds to me like you want to meaningfully reduce the RTT while retaining full control of the cache behaviour, so you can set a really long cache TTL.  The best price/performance solution IMO is to deploy your own cache servers running CentOS 7 + NGINX with proxy_cache turned on and enough disk space, and deploy a cache server for each major region (e.g. west coast and east coast).  Your end users could select the region closest to them, or your could add some code to automatically detect the closest regional cache server.

Deploying these cache servers on AWS EC2 is definitely an option.  Your end users will probably see much better performance than by connecting to AWS S3 directly, and there are no BW caps.

The current AWS pricing for your volume is about $0.09/GB for BW out to the internet.  Assuming your ~50 files at an average of 10GB, that's about $50/month for BW from cache servers to your end users - not bad?  You could start with c4.large for low/average usage regions ($79/month).  Higher usage regions might cost you about ~$150/month (c4.xl), ~$300/month (c4.2xl), etc.  You can get better pricing with spot instances and you can tune performance based on your business model (e.g. VIP vs Best-Effort).

In terms of being able to "fill the pipe" and sensitivity to network loss (e.g. congestion control, congestion avoidance), you may want to consider an optimized TCP stack like SuperTCP (full disclaimer, I'm the director of development).  The idea here is to have a per-connection auto-tuning TCP stack with a lot of engineering behind it, so it can fill huge pipes like the ones between AWS regions, and not overreact to network loss as regular TCP often does, especially when sending to Wi-Fi endpoints.

Unlike UDP solutions, it's a single-sided install (<5 min), you don't get charged for hardware or storage, you don't need to worry about firewalls, and it won't flood/kill your own network.  You'd want to install it on your sending devices: the regional cache servers and the origin server(s) that push new requests to the cache servers.

An optimized TCP stack can increase your throughput by 25%-85% over healthy networks, and I've seen anywhere from 2X to 10X throughput on lousy networks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think AWS is going to have a solution for you. At this point I would recommend looking into some other CDN providers like Akamai https://www.akamai.com/us/en/solutions/products/media-delivery/download-delivery.jsp that provide services specifically geared toward large file downloads. I don't think any of those services are going to be cheap though.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look into file acceleration software, like Signiant Flight or Aspera (disclosure: I'm a product manager for Flight). Large files (multiple GB in size) can be a problem for traditional HTTP transfers, especially over large latencies. File acceleration software goes over UDP instead of TCP, essentially masking the latency and increasing the speed of the file transfer.

One negative to using this approach is that your clients will need to download special software to download their files (since UDP is not supported natively in the browser), but you mentioned they use a download manager already, so that may not be an issue.

Signiant Flight is sold as a service, meaning Signiant will run the required servers in the cloud for you.

With file acceleration solutions you'll generally see network utilization of about 80 - 90%, meaning 80 - 90 Mbps on a 100 Mbps connection, or 800 Mbps on a 1 Gbps network connection.